# Configuring Apache Tomcat 7.0 to reject connections with expired client certificates

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, ssl, truststore

Consider `Apache Tomcat 7.0` configured to do client authentification (with connector's parameter `clientAuth` set to `true`).

It appears, that Tomcat trusts to expired client certificates by default, which are in its trusted store (allow them successfully do authentification).

Is it possible to configure `Apache Tomcat 7.0` do not trust and automatically reject such expired client certificates, even if they are in its trusted store?

It seems, this could be achieved by setting another `trustManagerClassName`, which is `X509TrustManagerImpl` by default. But I have no idea, does default algorithm really allows expired certificates? Which one from existing should be used here? Or I have to implement my own and put it `tomcat`'s libs?

**UPD**: I found very similar question: [Java trustmanager behavior on expired certificates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206859/java-trustmanager-behavior-on-expired-certificates)
but in answers there is no any appropriate solution in answers. I'm looking for existing more secure implemenenation of `X509TrustManager` which will check for certificate expiration.

Comment: Just to confirm: you have a truststore containing an expired certificate and Tomcat is continuing to trust that certificate when a client presents it? Did the cert expire since the last time Tomcat was started? Are you able to *remove* the certificate from the trust store in order to revoke it?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz 1) Yes, 2) Tomcat can be restarted in any time, it doesn't matter, 3) No, I'm not able to remove it from trust store.

Comment: Have you tried to use a `crlFile` to specify a certificate revocation list? I realize that X.509 should probably respect the expiration date of the cert, but this is an option if that isn't working as expected.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz No, we didn't. And we are looking for automatically rejecting expired certificates. It isn't CRL deal to contain list of expired certificates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to write your own `X509TrustManager` and use your own implementation of `checkClientTrusted`. Unfortunately, you may have to write a great deal of plumbing code unless you can find another class to extend to do the heavy-lifting of managing the trust store, the revocation, etc.

It might be worth your time using a debugger to trace-through the JRE's classes to see what's happening down in the default `X509TrustManager` -- perhaps it's configured incorrectly, or it's possible that Tomcat isn't enabling some features that would make sense to most people.

Just looking at decompiled sources from Java 8, it looks like it comes down to `sun.security.validator.SimpleValidator` which does seem to consider the (current) date when checking for validity of the certificate. I would expect a `CertificateExpiredException` to be thrown at some point by the JRE itself. I don't think Tomcat manages any of this.

[Another question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206859) has idle speculation about what happens but nothing really definitive.